# logout prevent back button java is not working i have tried all day but still can't get result,what am i missing?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, jsp

This is my Java class

```
package login.example;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@WebServlet("/UserOne")
public class UserOne extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7250065889869767422L;

    @Id
    private long id;
    private String name;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        long id = Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("id"));
        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        // String userRePass = request.getParameter("userRePassWord");

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/any", "root", "jaygurudev1@");
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("Select id,name from user where id=? and name=?");
            ps.setLong(1, id);
            ps.setString(2, name);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            // HttpServletRequest request = null;
            if (rs.next()) {
                HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
                session.setAttribute("id", id);
                session.setAttribute("name", name);
                ServletContext context = request.getServletContext();

                response.setHeader("Cache-control", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.1
                response.setHeader("Cache-control", "no-store");
                response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0
                response.setDateHeader("Expire", 0);
                RequestDispatcher dispatcher = context.getRequestDispatcher("/admin.jsp");
                dispatcher.forward(request, response);
                // or you can write whole thing in one line as ........

                // getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/success").forward(request,
                // response);

            } else {
                // request.setAttribute("wrongUser", userName);

                ServletContext context = request.getServletContext();

                response.setHeader("Cache-control", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.1
                response.setHeader("Cache-control", "no-store");
                response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0
                response.setDateHeader("Expire", 0);

                RequestDispatcher dispatcher = context.getRequestDispatcher("/login.jsp");
                dispatcher.forward(request, response);

                // or you can write whole thing in one line as ........
                // getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/fail").forward(request,
                // response);
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

This is my login.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="text-align: center">
        <h1>admin login</h1>
        <%
            response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1
            response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0
            response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
        %>
        <form action="/UserOne" method="get">
            <label for="id">Id</label> <input name="id" /> <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" />
            <button type="submit">Login</button>
        </form>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my admin.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page import="java.io.IOException"%>
<%@page import="java.io.PrintWriter"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    background-image: url(/images/admin.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-size: 640px 640px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <%
        response.setHeader("Cache-control", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.1
        response.setHeader("Cache-control", "no-store");
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0
        response.setDateHeader("Expire", 0);
    %>
    <a href="/userone">get all users</a>
    <h3>view user</h3>

    getMobileInfo
    <a href="/indexone">get all mobile details</a>


    <form action="/LogoutServlet" method="get">
        <input type="submit" value="logout">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

This is logout servlet

```
package login.example;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@WebServlet(name = "LogoutServlet", urlPatterns = { "/LogoutServlet" })
public class LogoutServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public LogoutServlet() {
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.removeAttribute("id");
        session.removeAttribute("name");
        request.getSession(false);
        session.invalidate();
        out.println("Thank you,you are successfully logged out");
        // response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate");

        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        httpResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1
        httpResponse.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0
        httpResponse.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.

        // request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp").include(request, response);
        response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
    }

}
```

What should I add or remove in order to get desired output such as it does not show previous page after I logged out? What is wrong with my code? Should I need any dependency or anything else to achieve this? How to solve this?

my url is like `http://localhost:8080/home.html`
then `http://localhost:8080/login.jsp?`
and `http://localhost:8080/UserOne?id=1&name=ritu`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have added below code in every jsp page which i want as secure page

```
<%
        if (session.getAttribute("id_name") == null && (session.getAttribute("name_name") == null)) {
            response.sendRedirect("/home.html");
        }
    %>
```

no need to write this below code in springboot,as springboot automatically add below code

```
<%
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0
    response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
%>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you click back button the the url (`/UserOne?id=1&name=ritu`) submits the old id and name making it to login to the page again. Send the login credentials in post parameter to fix the issue.

ie: In login.jsp the submit method should be post

Comment: i have used session in my UserOne class and LogoutServlet class @Vignesh Varadharajan

Comment: yes,i have changed that then when i click submit it goes to http://localhost:8080/admin.jsp

Comment: admin.jsp page is still showing

Comment: You need to check if the session is valid in logout.jsp and if it is not valid you need to redirect the page to home page.

Comment: in which way? i should check that?

Comment: what changes should i have to done? @Vignesh Varadharajan

Comment: Add below code in admin.jsp :   
   if(session.isNew()){
    response.sendRedirect("/login.jsp");
   }

Comment: yes ,now it works totally fine @Vignesh Vardharajan